# How to solve Type error: Not converted during string. New to python

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

Why would this error be occurring?  Help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot seem to get this to function.

Exception has occurred: TypeError
not all arguments converted during string formatting
File "C:\Users\toril\Downloads\scrape2.py", line 25, in 
resp = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()

```
import requests
page = 1
url = f"https://api-prod.grip.events/1/container/4368/thing/promoted/detail?search=&sort=name&order=asc&type_id=4907,4906,5265,4964,4904,1026,4908&promotion_level=premium"
headers = {
        'authority': 'api-prod.grip.events',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-gb',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"1a-s3B6blipWxCo2IriQlJeaz0uh7I"',
    'login-source': 'web',
    'origin': 'https://connect.money2020.com',
    'referer': 'https://connect.money2020.com/money2020europe/app/home/network/list/34589',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'x-authorization': '2cxxxxx7-c624-4xx0-8578-adxxxxxxeb69',
    'x-grip-version': 'Web/8.3.11',
        }
        
with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for page in range(1, 1000):
        resp = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()
        contacts = resp["data"]
        for contact in contacts:
            target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"],  contact["job_industry"])
            f.write(target + "\n")
            print(target)
```

Comment: `url` doesn't have a `%d` placeholder to for `page` to be substituted into.

Comment: You need to add `&page=%d` to the URL.

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve] from your code. Please also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: page = 1 
url = "https://api-prod.grip.events/1/container/4368/search?search=&sort=name&order=asc&type_id=4907,4906,5265,4964,4904,1026,4908&page=%d"


Could you asssist with the pagination? I have the data pulling it, but only from one single page now. Thank you !